# How to publish outcome of python operation as SNS message

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sns

As a novice, I have a simple python problem to generate a random number and publish that number to SNS topic.  I know how to send SNS message `(Message='Hello, World'.)`  How do I instead have it send my random number?

I have looked everywhere for an answer.

To generate a random number:

```
for x in range(0, 5):
    from random import randint
    print("Printing random integer ", randint(1, 5))
    from time import sleep
    sleep(5)
```

To publish SNS:

```
import boto3
# Use Amazon SNS
sns = boto3.client('sns')
# Publish a message to an SNS topic
response = sns.publish(
TopicArn='abcdefghijkl',
Message='Hello, World',
)
# Print the response
print(response)
```

I expect the message to be the random numbers.

Comment: As an aside, you've put your imports in a for loop. Good practice is to put them at the very top

Comment: I don't know what `SNS` is, but since `Message='Hello, World'` works, why not `Message=str(randint(1, 5))`?

Comment: Thank you a million times! I spent 20 hours trying to figure this out.  You resolved it.